# Boundary layers: approximately satisfying BC

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, asymptotics, perturbation-theory

I am working on a boundary layer problem for a second order linear ODE. A simpler problem which I think still illustrates the issue I am having is

$$\varepsilon y''-y'+y=0,y(0)=0,y(1)=1$$

where $\varepsilon > 0$ is a small parameter. This problem (unlike my actual problem) in fact admits an exact solution, namely

$$\frac{e^{\lambda_2 x}-e^{\lambda_1 x}}{e^{\lambda_2}-e^{\lambda_1}}$$

where

$$\lambda_1,\lambda_2=\frac{1 \pm \sqrt{1-4\varepsilon}}{2 \varepsilon}.$$

For small $\varepsilon > 0$, $\lambda_1$ is a large positive number, namely $\frac{1}{\varepsilon}+O(1)$, while $\lambda_2$ is a positive number of order $1$, namely $1+O(\varepsilon)$.

Upon sorting out minus signs, this means that the solution above grows very fast near $1$ and is very small far away from $1$. Accordingly, I've developed an "inner" boundary layer solution near $x=1$. This goes through the usual way by changing variables to $z=\frac{x-1}{\varepsilon}$, assuming that $\frac{d^2 y}{dz^2},\frac{dy}{dz}$ and $y$ are all $O(1)$ near $x=1$, and balancing the leading order terms. From this I get a leading order solution of $e^{\frac{x-1}{\varepsilon}}$ for $|x-1|=O(\varepsilon)$.

Now my problem arises on the rest of the interval. For the leading order outer solution, we consider $y'=y$, and get $y=Ce^x$. My problem is now essentially in identifying $C$. I can take it to be $0$ to match the left boundary condition, but this doesn't seem right, because the composite solution from this procedure is $e^{\frac{x-1}{\varepsilon}}$ over the whole interval, which fails to satisfy the left boundary condition (at least exactly). I can subtract off $e^{-\frac{1}{\varepsilon}}$ to force the left boundary condition to hold (which has a negligible impact on the error in the DE itself), but then the *right* boundary condition doesn't hold.

Should I be thinking about this differently? Do I need to go to higher order in order to get a reasonable result? It seems to me that I will, because a "reasonable" first order linear ODE beginning with value zero will always just stay at zero. So to start at zero and not stay there I need to consider a truly second order problem. But this is more difficult in my actual problem, and it seems that the method should be more or less universal.

Comment: I can't answer ur question direclty but i am almost sure that this problem is considered in detail in the book of Bender and Orszag

Comment: What is $\epsilon$?

Comment: @JanEerland A small parameter, it has no definite value in this context.

Comment: @Ian Maybe you can solve the question (the first one in your question) using Laplace Transform

Comment: @JanEerland I know how to get the exact solution of the equation that I wrote down, it is a standard problem in elementary ODEs. Indeed I did that in the question itself. The point is to be able to replace that equation with $\varepsilon y''+a(x) y'+b(x)y=0$, where $a,b$ are essentially arbitrary continuous functions except that we require $a$ to have a definite sign. For this there is no hope of constructing an exact solution and then approximating the exact solution.

Comment: @tired They do handle the general case of $\varepsilon y''+a(x)y'+b(x)y=0$ where $a,b$ are continuous and $a$ has one sign. The result that they get (for this simpler problem and my actual problem) agrees with what I have written. It's just that what I've written seems somewhat wrong, because of the boundary conditions only being asymptotically satisfied.

Comment: Your boundary layer scaling gives you $y''+y'=0$, in the boundary layer the $y$ term will be negligible compared to the first and second derivative terms.

Comment: The real solution to this problem is to use a WKB expansion, $y=\exp \left(\epsilon^{-\alpha} S_0(x)+S_1(x)+\epsilon^{\alpha}S_2(x)+\cdots\right)$.

Comment: @David You're right that this boundary layer setup actually gives $Ce^{\frac{x-1}{\varepsilon}}+D$. But when you asymptotically match to the zero function and the BCs, you get what I said. I suppose you could use WKB instead, which would essentially absorb the exponential decay into the prefactor and leave a reasonable function behind. But how can I write $y=fg$ in order to get an ODE not involving $g'$, when my actual ODE has nonconstant coefficients?

Comment: WKB theory works fine with nonconstant coefficients, I don't think I understand the question. What are $f$ and $g$?

Comment: @David The way I learned WKB theory focused on second order ODEs with no first derivative term. I learned to remove the first derivative term by writing $y=fg$, then set all terms involving $g'$ equal to zero. So you get a first order ODE for $f$. In the constant coefficient problem above this goes through easily: you want $\varepsilon (f''g+2f'g'+fg'')-(f'g+g'f)+fg=0$ and $2 \varepsilon f'g'-g'f=0$, so we can choose $f=e^{\frac{x}{2 \varepsilon}}$. This gives an ODE for $g$ which doesn't involve $g'$, which enables the procedure that I learned.

Comment: @David (Cont.) But the manipulations are harder when the coefficient on the first derivative is nonconstant. In that case $f$ has to be solved by an integrating factor and then differentiated twice to get the ODE for $g$, so I have reason to believe that the result would be somewhat complicated. Is there a more direct route for the context of second order equations with a first derivative term?

Comment: I don't have a whole heap of experience with WKB theory, you obviously know what you're doing so I could have misunderstood the issue. I'll write up a brief answer and you can see if it is helpful. I wont be able to do it for a couple of hours.

Comment: @David I see that you can just force WKB to work even though the result may turn out differently if you don't start by removing the $y'$ term.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WKB expansion is
$$ y(x)=\exp\left(\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n(x)\right), $$
where $\delta=\epsilon^\alpha$. The derivative of $y$ is
$$ y'(x)=\left[\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n'(x)\right]y(x), $$
and the second derivative is,
$$ y''(x)=\left[\frac{1}{\delta^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n'(x)\right)^2+\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n''(x)\right]y(x). $$

So, substituting into the ODE and factoring out the exponentials, you get
$$\left[\frac{\epsilon}{\delta^2}\left(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n'(x)\right)^2+\frac{\epsilon}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n''(x)\right]-\left[\frac{1}{\delta}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\delta^nS_n'(x)\right]+1=0. $$
You now have to find a distinguished limit to find $\delta$. The two largest terms in the expansion are $S_0'(x)^2\epsilon/\delta^2$ and $S_0'(x)/\delta$. To balance these, choose $\delta=\epsilon$. (This is the same as the boundary layer scaling you get from normal boundary layer theory).

Now, pick out the leading order eikonal equation, at $O(\epsilon^{-1})$:
$$ \left(S_0'(x)\right)^2-S_0'(x)=0,$$
and the first order transport equation, at $O(1)$:
$$ 2S_0'(x)S_1'(x)+S_0''(x)-S_1'(x)+1=0.$$

The first equation gives two solutions, $S_0(x)=x$, and $S_0(x)=0$. The first solution is an inner solution, and the second is an outer solution. You don't need to add constants of integration. The leading order solution is
$$y(x)=A\exp\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)+B, $$
and boundary conditions give
$$ y(x)=\frac{1-\exp\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}\right)}{1-\exp\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}\right)}. $$

The solution to the transport equation is, for the $S_0(x)=0$ solution,
$$ S_1(x)=x,$$
and for the $S_0(x)=x$ solution,
$$ S_1(x)=-x.$$
This gives the two-term solution,
$$ y(x)=C\exp\left(x\right)+D\exp\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}-x\right). $$
Boundary conditions give the final two-term solution as
$$ y(x)=\frac{\exp\left(x\right)-\exp\left(\frac{x}{\epsilon}-x\right)}{\exp\left(1\right)-\exp\left(\frac{1}{\epsilon}-1\right)}. $$
A nice thing about WKB theory is that it gives you the inner and outer solutions together, you don't need to do asymptotic matching.

Bender and Orszag's book has a great section about WKB theory.

Here's a picture of the one and two term solutions, along with a numerical solution, for $\epsilon=0.2$.
[image]

Comment: I used a somewhat different form of the WKB ansatz than this but I got good results. Thanks for the suggestion to use WKB in the first place.

Comment: What form did you do--I'm still learning this stuff and I'd be interested to know. Glad I could help somewhat.

Comment: I took $y=fg$, substituted that into the ODE and obtained a new ODE not involving $g'$, by solving a first order ODE for $f$. Then I took $g(x)=e^{\theta(x)/\varepsilon} h(x)$ and plugged everything in. This worked straightforwardly in my actual problem, which had a nonconstant coefficient on the $y'$ (but with a definite sign).