# Singular perturbation theory involving exponentials

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, boundary-value-problem, perturbation-theory

Suppose we're given the following second order ODE
\begin{align}
-\epsilon x''(t)=e^{x(t)}-1
\end{align}
with boundary conditions
\begin{align}
x(0)=0,\quad x(1)=1.
\end{align}
Suppose $\epsilon>0$ is a small parameter. Is it possible to study this problem using singular perturbation theory/asymptotic matching?
I can only seem to find examples where the right hand side is more or less algebraic.

Comment: Do you suspect there is a boundary layer at $t=1$, or what?

Comment: Yes, I guess that's the idea, since if $\epsilon=0$, then $x\equiv 0$ would be a solution, which satisfies only the boundary condition at $t=0$.

Comment: The problem that I see is that there is no elimination of terms; for example, in the typical situation with boundary layers in second order linear equations, there is a $y'$ term that must balance the $y''$ term. But here there is only one term that responds to the change in the time scaling.

Comment: I suppose you can use a conservation law type approach to get $x'^2=x'(0)^2+2\epsilon^{-1}(x-e^x+1)$ on a convenient interval. Assume $x'(0)$ isn't huge since that's in the outer solution, so now you change variables in accordance with $|x-1|=O(\delta)$, you have the LHS being $O(\delta^{-2})$ and the second term on the RHS being $O(\epsilon^{-1})$ hence $\delta=\epsilon^{1/2}$ is the right scaling.

Comment: (Cont.) But although you can throw away the $x'(0)$ term, you still end up with the inner problem of $x'^2=2(x-e^x+1),x(0)=1$ in the inner layer, which doesn't seem that much easier than the original problem.

Comment: (Ignore that "convenient interval" bit, that was an edit fail.)

Comment: Never mind, the boundary layer approach will not work here because of the same reason it didn't work in my old question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1717022/boundary-layers-approximately-satisfying-bc . Maybe you can try WKB instead.